# Output Headline with Image

Tags: r, image, shiny, output

I am just learning R Shiny and have been playing around with the various examples in the gallery.  For the "Image Output" example:

http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/image-output.html

I was wondering how I might be able to include an image headline when I select either the chainring or smiley radio button.  For example after selecting "smiley" I would like the title "Smiley" to display below the image.  Thank you for your help.  Below is the code that is also included in the link above. (Some of it was intentionally deleted for clarity).  Thank you

```
library(png) # For writePNG function

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

# A temp file to save the output.
# This file will be automatically removed later by
# renderImage, because of the deleteFile=TRUE argument.
outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".png")

# Generate the image and write it to file
x <- matrix(rep((0:(width-1))/(width-1), height), height,
            byrow = TRUE)
y <- matrix(rep((0:(height-1))/(height-1), width), height)
pic <- gauss2d(x, y, input$r)
writePNG(pic, target = outfile)

# Return a list containing information about the image
list(src = outfile,
     contentType = "image/png",
     width = width,
     height = height,
     alt = "This is alternate text")

}, deleteFile = TRUE)


# image2 sends pre-rendered images
output$image2 <- renderImage({
if (is.null(input$picture))
  return(NULL)

if (input$picture == "face") {
  return(list(
    src = "images/face.png",
    contentType = "image/png",
    alt = "Face"
  ))
} else if (input$picture == "chainring") {
  return(list(
    src = "images/chainring.jpg",
    filetype = "image/jpeg",
    alt = "This is a chainring"
  ))
}

}, deleteFile = FALSE)
 })







shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Client data and query string example"),

fluidRow(
column(4, wellPanel(
  sliderInput("r", "Radius :", min = 0.05, max = 1,
              value = 0.2, step = 0.05),
  radioButtons("picture", "Picture:",
              c("chainring", "face"))
)),
column(4,
  imageOutput("image1", height = 300),
  imageOutput("image2")
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Image title"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("obs", "Number of observations:",
                            min = 0, max = 1000,  value = 500)
        ),
        mainPanel(
                imageOutput("myImage"),
                uiOutput("text")

        )
      )
    ))
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

            output$myImage <- renderImage({
                    outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')

                    png(outfile, width=400, height=300)
                    hist(rnorm(input$obs), main = "")
                    dev.off()

                    list(src = outfile,
                         contentType = 'image/png',
                         width = 400,
                         height = 300,
                         alt = "This is alternate text")
            }, deleteFile = TRUE)
            histogramTitle <- reactive({
                    paste("<h5>", input$obs, " observation used to create the histogram</h5>", sep = "")
            })
            output$text <- renderUI({   
                    HTML(as.character(histogramTitle()))
            })
    })
```